# Finding kernel, range, and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let L : $P_{3}$ → $P_{3}$ be given by $L(p) = p^n$.  I'm trying to find the kernel and range of L and the dimension of kernel and range.  I think I know how to find kernel and range, but I'm not sure about dimension.  ker(L) =  {p|$p^n$ = 0} = {0}.  range(L) = {0}.

Comment: What is $n$? And how did you get $\text{Im}L = \{ 0 \} ?$

Comment: I am not sure that your function $L$ is well defined. Are you taking $P_3$ to be the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 3? In that case $L(x^3)= (x^3)^n$ which might not be in $P_3$.